# Using a variable from outer scope in a sub called in foreach

Tags: perl, foreach, scope, subroutine

I am using cygwin. 
What this script does is load the iphone pics that I have loaded into a directory on the desktop. 
It opens it up in image viewer, to let me take a look at the picture.

```
system("cygstart $dirname/$oldfile") ;
```

Then it gives me the option to rename the picture. It is throwing errors though, and not renaming the picture.

```
Use of uninitialized value $oldfile in concatenation (.) or string at ./rename_image.pl line 29, <STDIN> line 6.
```

oldfile is a global varaible, the functions should see the variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict ;
use warnings ;

my $oldfile;
my $new_name;
my $dirname = "/cygdrive/c/Users/walt/Desktop/iphonepics/bunk_box/";
opendir(DIR, $dirname) or die "Cannot open dir: $!";

my @files = readdir(DIR);
foreach $oldfile (@files) {
        system("cygstart $dirname/$oldfile") ;
        print "Do you want to rename $oldfile ? ";
        my $input = <STDIN> ;
        chomp $input ;
        if($input =~ m/^[y]$/i) {
                rename_file() ;
        } else {
        my $doo = 1 ;
        }
}

sub rename_file {
        use File::Copy qw(move) ;
        print "New name:\n" ;
        my $new_name = <STDIN> ;
        chomp $new_name ;
        move "$dirname/$oldfile", "$dirname/$new_name";
        return ;
}
```

Comment: Are we seeing 100% of the code? There is no possible way for rename_file to have been executed except from within the `foreach` loop?

Comment: This is unrelated to the warning you are seeing, but have you noticed that your paths will look like this? `/cygdrive/c/Users/walt/Desktop/iphonepics/bunk_box//foobar`  (In other words, you're concatenating a string that ends with / to the filename, using another / in your concatenation.

Comment: Yes this is the code, and no, it does not rename any files. It so far does not work as planned. Also, no I did not notice the extra slash in the $dirname variable. what is the proper, accepted way to delineate an absolute path as a variable - ending in a slash or open (with the slash being assumed)

Comment: All I want to do is rename some pictures - the cygstart is just do I can see what picture is loaded into the array, the visual helps me figure uot a name for it. Most of the Pictures are named IMG_* by default.

Comment: Doubling a slash should have absolutely no effect (but I don't use Cygwin much, please test).  Whether you include it in the directory or when you compose a path is a matter of choice of the convention you want: either `$dir = '.../';` and `$file = $dir . $name;` OR `$dir = '...'` (no slash) and `$file = "$dir/$name"`.  But you might as well use both, to be on the safe side.

Comment: `use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile); my $full_path = catfile($path, $filename);` ...this is a core module and should eliminate things like duplicated slashes. In your particular use case I'm not sure duplicated slashes matter, but they're sloppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach $oldfile (@files)` does not assign values to the `my $oldfile` declared at the top. That one is a lexical variable, not global, and in such a case a new lexical `$oldfile` is created for the loop's scope. This is a particular property of `foreach` alone. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42244426/4653379) for details.

Since the `$oldfile` in `foreach` is a lexical in a *dynamic scope* it is invisible to the sub. But the sub sees `my $oldfile` declared for the static scope of the file.  From [Private Variables via my()](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29)

> ... lexical variables declared with `my` are totally hidden from the outside world, including any called subroutines. This is true if it's the same subroutine called from itself or elsewhere--every call gets its own copy.
>
> This doesn't mean that a `my` variable declared in a statically enclosing lexical scope would be invisible. Only dynamic scopes are cut off. For example, ...

That `$oldfile` at the top, seen by the sub, stays as it was before the loop, uninitialized.

Altogether, a simple "fix" to get the expected behavior is to make `$oldfile` on top a global variable, so to replace `my $oldfile` with `our $oldfile`.<sup>†</sup>

However, why rely on global variables?  Why not pass to functions what they need

```
foreach my $oldfile (@files) {
    ...
    if (...) {
        rename_file($dirname, $oldfile);
    ...
}

sub rename_file {
    my ($dirname, $oldfile) = @_;
    ...
}
```

You *are* nicely using `strict` already and declaring everything else.  Then you don't need, and should not have, the file-wide lexical `my $oldfile;` declared on top.

When you declare a variable in a sub, it is shielded from variables with the same name outside the sub's scope. So here you *know* what `$oldfile` is – it is exactly what you passed to the function.

That way your sub also has a well defined interface and does not depend on arbitrary values in the surrounding code. This is crucial for clear delineation of scope and for modularity.

More generally, using a global variable while `strict` is in place and other things declared is like planting a mine for the maintenance programmer, or for yourself the proverbial six months later.

I suggest to also read [Coping with Scoping](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/TPJ/1998/vol3_4/tpj0304-0001.html) by Mark-Jason Dominus.

---

<sup>†</sup> I don't recommend this unless there is a very specific and solid reason for a global-like [our](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) variable.

Comment: This is all sound advice, but if the code we're seeing is 100% of the code the OP is using, the warning should not be possible, as it would mean that `readdir` populated `@files` with an undef entry, and furthermore, that the user of the script managed to still say "Y" to the question of whether to move the file, when the filename didn't show up in the screen output.  Given it's unlikely that we're seeing the code that produced this warning, it's hard to come to the conclusion that this answer actually solves the OP's question.

Comment: @DavidO  I added the explanation for the warning, thanks for prompting it. As for the "impossible" -- it isn't, it's just how it has to be.  Try it, give some value to `my $oldfile` when it is declared.

Comment: Yes - this is the code in its entirety - all it does is open up the photo in photoviewer. I look at the photo, which new photos taken with my iphone typically are called IMG_1234.jpg. If I like it I hit yes and rename the photo. Anything left IMG_* will be removed from the directory.

Comment: @capser  Thank you for confirming it -- I thought so and answered your question about the particular error.  Did you mean to respond to DavidO? (If so tag your comment with AT-DavidO)

Comment: @capser Please let me know if I need to explain things more in this answer.  A note: while it is enough to replace `my $oldfile` with `our $oldfile`, as explained, I do not recommend that -- better pass things to functions, as shown.  (Unless you have a lot of code that relies on globals...)

Comment: @zdim - No thank you very much I did not understand why the sub did not see the my variable, like I did not understand why I initialized the variable with strict, and then getting uninitialized errors. This was actually a very good lesson.

Comment: @capser  Yes, in my opinion this is a good  question, that is important as a good lesson.  I hope that I explained it well enough, if not please let me know what is unclear in my answer and I'll rephrase things.  Thank you for attribution.